# "Could not launch activity" in espresso test

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

Here is my [full code](https://github.com/roroco/ro-h/tree/could-not-launch-activity), when I test following code with "Android Tests", it raise error "Could not launch activity"

```
//TestPlayer.kt
public class PlayerTest : ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Player>(Player::class.java) {
    override fun setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        getActivity()
    }

    fun testPlayer() {
        onView(withId(R.id.player)).perform(doubleClick())
    }
}
```

I doesn't find any output in android monitor, how to debug it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to declare `Player` activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".Player"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
```